# How to Display Multiple Google Maps with popup buttons in one page

Tags: javascript, html, popup, maps

In the following script I want to make several maps available in one page, but they must appear in a popup window when I click the correspondent button. So, there will be several buttons in that page, one for each map and the maps appear in the popups.

The first button is ok, but the second does not work. What can I do to make it work and add others?

Thanks!

```
<html>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: "Map",
                width: 600,
                hright: 450,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                open: function () {

    var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.520266,73.856406);
    var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.579943,77.330006);
    var myOptions1 =
    {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var myOptions2 =
    {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_1"), myOptions1);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);

    var myMarker1 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: latlng1,
        map: map1,
        title:"Local"
   });

    var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: latlng2,
        map: map2,
        title:"Local"
    });

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>


<input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Open Map 1"/>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
<div id="map_canvas_1" style="height: 380px; width: 580px;"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />

<input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Open Map 2"/>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
<div id="map_canvas_2" style="height: 380px; width: 580px;"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starter you should't have doubled id's in the same HTML page. The event handler will always refer to one or another. Test This by removing the first button HTML and see if the second button actually opens the second map.

Comment: I did, the second button does not open

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: nope! nothing appears to me. Just the button remains inactive.

Comment: It's exactly as i said. Removing the first button/dialog html and removing `var map1 = new google.maps.....` solved the issue and displayed the second map. Of course this is not a complete solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is not really [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but solves your problem.**

Have a look at it to understand what's going on, then you can refactor to achieve a shorter code (which is important if you have more than two maps). Looking at the official documentation might help.

```
    <html>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnShow_map1").click(function () {

                $("#dialog_map1").dialog({
                    modal: true, 
                    title: "Map",
                    width: 600,
                    hright: 450,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    open: function () {

                        var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(18.520266,73.856406);
                        var myOptions1 =
                        {
                            zoom: 15,
                            center: latlng1,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                        };


                        var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_1"), myOptions1);

                        var myMarker1 = new google.maps.Marker(
                        {
                            position: latlng1,
                            map: map1,
                            title:"Local"
                       });

                    }
                });
            });

            $("#btnShow_map2").click(function () {

                $("#dialog_map2").dialog({
                    modal: true, 
                    title: "Map",
                    width: 600,
                    hright: 450,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    open: function () {

                        var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.579943,77.330006);
                        var myOptions2 =
                        {
                            zoom: 10,
                            center: latlng2,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                        };  


                        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_2"), myOptions2);

                        var myMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
                        {
                            position: latlng2,
                            map: map2,
                            title:"Local"
                        });

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>


    <input id="btnShow_map1" type="button" value="Open Map 1"/>
    <div id="dialog_map1" style="display: none">
    <div id="map_canvas_1" style="height: 380px; width: 580px;"></div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <input id="btnShow_map2" type="button" value="Open Map 2"/>
    <div id="dialog_map2" style="display: none">
    <div id="map_canvas_2" style="height: 380px; width: 580px;"></div>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

You cannot bind an event handler to multiple items using one id.
Use classes for that.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp):

> **id**

Specifies a **unique** id for the element. Naming rules:

- Must contain at least one character
- Must not contain any space characters
- In HTML, all values are case-insensitive